# Updating barplot in real time using pyqtgraph

Tags: python-3.x, qt, user-interface, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to create a little widget using pyqtgraph that updates in real time. I made this work with no problem using a line plot. However, I would like to do this with a bar plot using the `addPlot` method in `pg.GraphicsWindow`.

Here's the basic setup I have so far:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title='Spectrum Analyzer')
self.spectrum = self.win.addPlot(
            title='SPECTRUM', row=1, col=1
        )

# Plot the init data -- I want this to be a bar plot
self.obj = self.spectrum.plot(pen='m', width=3)

# Update data content in plot -- stick in loop
self.obj.setData(data_x, data_y)
```

I like the rapid features of `addPlot` and would rather not use `pg.plot().addItem(pg.BarGraphItem())` in a loop due to high latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
# initialization
self.obj = pg.BarGraphItem()
self.spectrum.addItem(self.obj)

# update
self.obj.setOpts(...)
```

?